MacBookAir M2 blackscreen and not responding
A colleague of mine gave me their Mac Book Air M2 and says that it's broken (I know, nice error report). On first start (after pressing the power button) the login screen appeared, but I can't input anything, also the trackpad doesn't respond (not even haptic feedback, like if the device is off). Holding down the power button resets everything, I could login as normal. Did some thermal stress test for over 30min, no problem.
Then after some time it just locked, disabled the screen and when pressing the on button again I was stuck as before, no input possible.
Now I try to delete and reset the whole device with recovery manager. While installing the OS from scratch near the end it turned off the screen again. The screen is black, trackpad seems off (no haptic feedback). When clicking the power button once the screen flashes real quick, showing the current progress of the reset but turns off immediately. Holding down the power button and restarting completely does make it interactable again, but then the reset progress gets reset.
It's not the standby timer that causes this, because while resetting I interacted with the trackpad multiple times to not let it go to sleep. While writing this (still in recovery install, black screen, screen flashing when pressing power button) it just chimed and turned off completely.
Update: I just connected an external display, keyboard and mouse to it. Screen shows everything as normal, keyboard works, mouse works. Internal screen still "dead", trackpad "off" and keyboard does also nothing.
Update 2: On the external screen the reinstall now "finished" but has an error "An error occurred while preparing the installation. Try running this application again.". So it failed the reinstall of macOS
Any clues what the case could be? It's almost unused, not much happened on the device, so it's really strange.

Without putting the laptop on my workbench, I think this may be a hardware problem of some sort and it is hard to diagnose definitively.
